# Angular content child with ng-template doesn't work

Tags: angular

I have the following directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appTest]'
})
export class TestDirective {
  @ContentChild(ButtonComponent, { static: false }) button;
  constructor() { }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.button);
  }

}
```

And I want to use it with `<ng-template>`:

```
<ng-template appTest>
  <app-button></app-button>
</ng-template>
```

But it doesn't work. I can't get a reference to the button. The log is `undefined`. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

> You can't retrieve elements or directives that are in other
> components' templates, since a component's template is always a black
> box to its ancestors [ContentChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild#description)

What you can do is using `templateRef` & `viewContainer`

> You'll acquire the  contents with a TemplateRef and
> access the view container through a ViewContainerRef.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appTest]'
})
export class TestDirective {

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {

    var embeddedViewRef = viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);

    for (var node of embeddedViewRef.rootNodes) {

      //Your button component
      console.log(node);
    }
  }

}
```